# How to generate Personal Access Token for github (enterprise/organisation account) from shell script or command line?

Tags: bash, shell, github, command-line

I am trying to write an automation script for configuring git, but since its for an organisation account and two factor authentication, I need to generate personal access token for authorisation.

I have already tried the below code but it doesnt return anything.

```
token=$(curl -u $uname:$passwd --silent -d '{"scopes":["user"]}' "https://api.github.organisation.com/authorizations" | grep -o '[0-9A-Fa-f]\{40\}')
```

I want to get the token value into a variable like above.

Comment: how "silent" is `--silent`? Your assignment to `token` looks correct, so get it to work first just as `curl -u ...URL`? Good luck.

Comment: this doesnt work for organisation account, only for personal ones. I think because of 2 step verification.